# Calculating distance in a 2D array, Non diagonal

Tags: java, language-agnostic, distance

I have the following implemented in Java:

```
  [1,1][1,2][1,3][1,4]
  [2,1][2,2][ B ][2,4]
  [ A ][3,2][3,3][3,4]
```

I want to be able to calculate the Minimum distance between [ A ] and [ B ], without moving diagonally, i have searched online, but I'm not really sure how to word what I'm looking for. so far i have been able to calculate the diagonal distance using:

```
dMin = Math.min(dMin, Math.abs((xDistance - yDistance)));
```

Could some one please give me an algorithm i could look for online? any help is appreciated. thanks for you time :)

Expected output is:

```
Distance = 3 //Not Distance = 2 (as it would be diagonally).
```

Comment: For the record, that's also not how you calculate the diagonal.  What you need for that is the [Pythagorean theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_theorem): `Distance = SquareRoot(xDistance*xDistance + yDistance*yDistance)` - in this case, approximately 2.23.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called [Manhattan Distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taxicab_geometry) and can easily be computed by:

```
distance = abs(ydistance) + abs(xdistance)
```

That is, the number of cells you must travel vertically, plus the number of cells you must travel horizontally, much like a taxi driving through a grid of city streets.

Answer (score 6):

You want the absolute difference between the x values of the points, plus the absolute difference between the y values of the points.

ie:

```
dMin = Math.abs(A.x - B.x) + Math.abs(A.y - B.y)
```

This is known as Manhattan Distance

Answer (score 2):

You want the difference along the `X` axis plus the difference along the `Y` axis.  Something like this:

```
int minDistance = Math.abs(A.x - B.x) + Math.abs(A.y - B.y);
```